# How to expose Web API to the Internet to grant ability to connect with a different computer on the same network

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, http, asp.net-web-api

I am having an issue connecting to my web api (via Postman)from a separate computer on the same network. I am Able to connect (Via Postman) if I am working on the same computer where the API is located. However When I attempt to connect to the same API (Via Postman) on a separate computer (within the same network). I receive an error stating

"Could not Send response
ECONNREFUSED"

I have tried to unblock SSL certificates.
I have also tried to add bindings to the applicationhost.config file

Neither of these have worked for me.
As a side note, The API does not have any Authentication associated with it so my guess is it has something to do with access to the web server where the API is housed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: We would need more information on how it’s run, where it’s bound, how firewall settings are etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Connect through Ip Address That should work.

For Example
on local it should be like this
http://localhost:8050/ParseXml

On Remote or other Pc
http://10.45.0.38:8050/ParseXml

Another thing is did you check if your system can successfully ping that system?

Comment: I switched the request from local host to the IP address. I got a response of "The request hostname is invalid" Full response:  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
 <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
 <h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
 <hr>
 <p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY>

</HTML>

Comment: Usually this error comes when your calling url is not correct.